# Starting an existing git project on new machine

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm currently working on a project (on **machine 1**) that is up-to-date with the github server. The project folder has multiple sub-folders some of which are *gitignore*-d and not stored on the server. I'm trying to have a copy of this project on **machine 2**. In order to get all the data, I copy-pasted contents from machine 1 (except the .git folder) to machine 2. Now, I would like to sync this (project on machine 2) with the git server.

I tried the following on machine 2, but I feel I'm doing something wrong. Here is what I tried-

```
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "first commit on machine 2"
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
git push origin master
```

I think this is wrong because on the github server, I can see all the files are being updated although there is no change to the files. Can someone please help me with the right solution for the problem of moving the existing project to another machine?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _"except the .git folder"_ - why? That is the git repo... -- creating a new repo like you have done has complicated things.

Comment: I did not copy the .git folder as I thought this folder has contents that are specific to a machine. I'm not quite sure how to move the project to a second machine. I'm familiar with working with git on one machine (simple git pull, git push) but this is confusing. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Copy the `.git` folder, this will save a lot of time.

Comment: Can you please write a solution? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

1. `git clone` the project on machine 2
2. Copy content from machine 1 to machine 2 (if possible only the ignored files to speed things up)

When copying from machine 1, the only changes would be to the ignored files and `git status` should not show any change.

---

Edit: as said in comments, the most straightforward forward way is to actually just copy everything from machine 1 (including `.git` folder).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering if I would be able to contribute to the project from both the machines if I copy the .git folder. I'm not planning to move to machine 2 completely, I would still like to write codes on machine 1 and be able to push/pull changes. Let me know what you think. Thank you.

Comment: You will be able to contribute from both machines